# how to input my code segment in my discussion?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, code-formatting

how to input my code in my question?

I want to input a segment of code to ask a question

but stackoverflow alway hints me that my format is not correct

but I really don't know how to make a good format

do you have any picture illustration to show me step by step??

Comment: [StackOverflow Formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Try [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+how+to+format+my+code&rlz=1C1KMZB_enUS562US562&oq=stackoverflow+how+to+format+my+code&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.5303j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) before asking questions here. The google link will show you how I found your answer in the first link of a google search.

Answer (score 3):

Highlight all your codes and press `ctrl + k` (control and K).

For example

```
<?php
echo 'foo';
?>
```

Or indent (press spacebar) 4 times, before the a line of text.

```
like this
```

To find help press the `?` button at the top-right of the text-area.

[image]

Comment: "This is example"... I accidentally an indefinite article.

Comment: I think you meant "I accidentally indefinite article" @Robert :-).

Comment: That's what I get for trying out a meta meta joke on a programming meta website.  How about *"Syntax Error - Missing Indefinite Article."*

Comment: I'm on the slow-thinking side. I'll catch it tomorrow maybe.